# C# version of HelloIntuitAnywhere demo - does anyone know Intuit app URLs to use?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Brand new to QuickBooks integration, so hello everyone.

Following the java step-by-step instructions for Hello World (intuit_anywhere demo app) becasue there doesn't seem to be a doc for the .Net version.

The second thing it tells you to do is go to "My Development Center" and create an app.  And it says to use the following values;

- Name of App:         HelloWorldIA
- Host Name Domain:    The host and domain of your web server
- App URL:         http:///HelloWorldIA
- Disconnect URL:            http:///HelloWorldIA/**disconnect.jsp**
- Manage Users URL:    http:///HelloWorldIA/**manageusers.jsp**
- OpenID URL:      http:///HelloWorldIA/**LoginInitServlet****

The problem is the pages used in the last three don't exist in the C# version and I can't figure out what to enter.

Has anyone done the C# version and know these values?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Disconnect URL: http://HelloWorldIA/Disconnect.aspx
Manage Users URL: http://HelloWorldIA <- Not used
OpenID URL: http://HelloWorldIA/DirectConnectToIntuit.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ASP.Net MVC sample app, you can use:

```
Open ID Url: http://HelloWorldIA/OpenId
```

This will make the flow work when using the "login via Intuit" button from your web page.